# Get Test cases from Test Plan using OTA

Tags: java, hp-quality-center, com4j

I have the following structure in QC

```
Test Plan > Subject > Sample(Folder Name) > Scenario (Sub Folder) > TC1 (Test Case )
```

How can i retrieve TC1 using OTA and Java. 
Written the following code to get the Test folders , but not able to get the test cases under the Scenario folder

```
ITreeManager iTreeManager = qcConnect.treeManager().queryInterface(ITreeManager.class);
ISubjectNode iSubNode = iTreeManager.nodeByPath("Subject\\Sample").queryInterface(ISubjectNode.class);
IList testFolders = iSubNode.newList();
  for (Com4jObject isys : testFolders) {
        System.out.println("Test folder : "+ isys.queryInterface(ISysTreeNode.class).());           
    }
```

How can I get to TC1 and update the fields in the test case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the ISubjectNode you want (the object that represents Test Plan folders), you can access the 'TestFactory' property of that folder to return a factory object that will let you access the tests stored in that folder.

I don't write Java, so here's my best attempt at what you need based on the code you provided:

```
// First access the TestFactory from the folder
ITestFactory iTestFact = iSubject.testFactory;

// Pull back a list of all tests.  Refer to OTA documentation on how to use filters on the list.
IList testList = iTestFact.newList();

// You can now iterate over the list of tests like you did subject folders
```